# htaccess redirect https://www.example.net to https://www.example.com/members/

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, url-rewriting

My title says it all. I tried the following, but it only works for the non-https version.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/members/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/members/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That's not doing it, thanks. I still just get a 'Your connection is not private' error.

Comment: Do you have https certificate for your site.

Comment: Yes. https is working great, thanks - just not the rewriterule.